# Is there a way to find my.cnf in shared hosting?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

I'm curious is there a way to find my.cnf in shared hosting or is this file can be configured just by DBAs and no one can set his/her own settings?

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES can imply some of it: may be useful to know...

Comment: You mean I can use SHOW VARIABLES to see some of mySQL variables that I can configure. Correct me if I'm wrong @gbn.

Comment: correct: my.cnf sets variables that can be read via SHOW. Some can be changed via SET too for testing without changing my.cnf. Note: you can't tell the difference between defaults and what is explicitly set in my.cnf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a shared hosting environment, you cannot access `my.cnf`

You can see the variables see other ways:

### SHOW VARIABLES

- `SHOW VARIABLES;` will show all variables that are set. Some can be dynamically changed within you session with the `SET` command. Some can be set in the server so that new DB Connections going forward can use the newly set value.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'` shows all innodb settings
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout'` shows all timeout setting
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'` shows all buffers

##INFORMATION_SCHEMA

You can also access the variables by means of the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database. The tables to access those values are

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/variables-table.html)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/variables-table.html)

The same requests using these tables are

- `SHOW VARIABLES;` becomes `SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_variables;`
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%'` becomes `SELECT * FROM information_schema .global_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE 'innodb%';`
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout'` becomes `SELECT * FROM information_schema .global_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE '%timeout';`
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'` becomes `SELECT * FROM information_schema .global_variables WHERE VARIABLE_NAME LIKE '%buffer%';`

The reason INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES exists is to see the setting your session has, in the event you change a variable during the session to something different form the global setting.

### Examples

- `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;` will now allow 1000 DB Connections
- `SET sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 8;` sets your session sort_buffer_size to 8M
- `SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 1024 * 1024 * 8;` sets session sort_buffer_size to 8M for all incoming DB Connections going forward

### CAVEAT

Please keep in mind that not all settings can be dynamically changed. Some values, such as [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size) (session or global) and [max_connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections) (global only [session is N/A]), such as [innodb_buffer_pool_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_buffer_pool_size) and [lower_case_table_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names), can only be changed by setting it in my.cnf and restarting mysqld.

[Click here for the List of Variables, their defaults, and their session characteristics](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html).

Comment: Really informative, thanks. I've checked my Cpanel, it seems that some hosting providers remove those two tables (Global & Session) from their INFORMATION_SCHEMA DB!